# How to create gradient for TChart Bar?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I created this in Excel. How can I create such an effect in my `TChart`? As you can see, the gradient is based on the minimum/maximum values.

[image: Same gradient for each bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GradientRelative property for the Bar series that should do this. However, I see it doesn't work as expected so I've added it to the defect list to be fixed for future releases (TJ71016478).

Comment: Thanks. I've found more than a couple of bugs in just a week now. I really hope they will be fixed in the near future.